# How do I apply mod_rewrite rules for Elastic Beanstalk instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, passenger

I've been learning bits and pieces about this environment. I have a Beanstalk instance configured and I want to ensure that all requests that resolve (using a catchall dns '*') end up being rewritten as www.example.com.

I do not have a http/conf.d folder -- and this is apparently due to some Passenger setup.

I believe I'm supposed to use .ebextensions -- but again I don't even know what file I would have to modify with it.

Comment: Did you get an acceptable answer on this elsewhere?

Comment: Not at all. Like the only answer that what given "it's pretty clear, although you may need a little trial and error..." -- I see... mmhmm. What you're going to need to do is find and edit the passenger config.erb ($(passenger-config --root)) via image patch. My 2p is that it's ugly as hell.

Answer (score -4):

> I believe I'm supposed to use .ebextensions -- but again I don't even know what file I would have to modify with it.

Well, the [.ebextensions documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html) is pretty clear, although you may need a little trial and error to get it exactly how you want it.

Also, Stack Overflow has [146 results for "ebextensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ebextensions). It might be worth taking a look at some of them for pointers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip... but my issue isn't "how" do I use .ebextensions or even where how to find .ebextensions here on SO. As mentioned in my question, I do not have a conf.d folder, which is where most of the configuration takes place. Another poster mentioned it was probably due to me being in a Passenger based instance.

Comment: I was responding to your last sentence. I was under the assumption that you knew _what_ to change, just not _how_. I pointed you in the direction of the _how_.

Comment: Why not add an `.htaccess` file to your app containing the rules you want?

Comment: I don't even know if I can do that. As mentioned above it was the knowledge of another member that gave me the idea that it was using passenger (this is the Beanstalk with load balancer -- defaults). If it was to use an .htaccess, there's no indication that mod_rewrite rules would even be allowed. (They usually are not allowed by default in .htaccess)